# why does this value not change when I turn it into a negative?

Tags: java, object

I am trying to write a class Rational that had a few methods relating to adding, subtracting, etc. I want to make it so that within the constructor, I add the values to the private variables and find the GCD to find simplify the fraction. The problem I run into is with my if statements. I want to check if the numbers within the object parameter are negative so I use the if statement to check. The only problem is when I run the program, it doesn't give me a negative value i.e. I have Rational p = new Rational(-24, 48) and it only returns 1/2.

```
public class TestRational {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Rational p = new Rational(-24, 48);
    }

    public Rational(long a, long b){
        numerator = a;
        denominator = b;
        boolean isNegative = false;
        if (numerator*denominator < 0)
            isNegative = true;
        long gd = gcd(numerator, denominator);
        numerator /= gd;
        denominator /= gd;
        if (isNegative)
            numerator = -numerator;;
    }

    private long gcd(long p, long q){
        //checks to see if numerator greater than denominator
        if(p<q)
            return gcd(q,p);
        if(Math.abs(q) == 0)
            return p;
        long remainder = Math.abs(p)%Math.abs(q);
        return gcd(Math.abs(q), Math.abs(remainder));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add Brackets to your if statements to make it clear what conditional branch the logic is taking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont need this

```
if (isNegative)
 numerator = -numerator;;
```

So the constructor becomes

```
public Rational(long a, long b){
 numerator = a;
 denominator = b;
 boolean isNegative = false;
 if (numerator*denominator < 0)
 isNegative = true;
 long gd = gcd(numerator, denominator);
 numerator /= gd;
 denominator /= gd;
}
```

Hope it works ...

Answer (score 1):

Unless your question asked you explicitly to use GCD and the range of `a` and `b` is not big, you can implement it simply with a loop:

```
public Rational(long a, long b){
    boolean isNegative = a < 0 || b < 0;
    a = Math.abs(a);
    b = Math.abs(b);
    for (int i = min(a, b); i >= 2; --i)
        if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0)
        {
            a /= i;
            b /= i;
        }
    numerator = isNegative ? -a : a;
    denominator = b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would like point some "avoidable mistakes" in your code.

1. Name of constructor must be same as name of class. **In your case it is not**.
2. use blocks for **if{ statements}** even if it contains single statement.
3. you have not declared type of local variable **numerator** and **denominator**
4. what **private variables** you are talking about ?

Pay little more attention to code while posting,  it will help you to get *good* answers to your question